# Fetching YouTube live-stream comments into a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, youtube, cors

I'm trying to build a React Webapp to group and display superchats while a livestream is running.

What I've tried so far (unsuccessfully) is to use the YouTube LiveChat API, however this requires authentication from the live stream owner (which I do not have)

The second thing I've tried is to use [youtube-chat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-chat), however this does not work. (I ran into CORS issues: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://consent.youtube.com/m?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fchannel%2FUCdQPeeJ0qGK6wWBiEJWcdsQ%2Flive&gl=NO&m=0&pc=yt&uxe=23983171&hl=en&src=1' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/channel/UCdQPeeJ0qGK6wWBiEJWcdsQ/live') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`. I've proxied all requests to https://www.youtube.com. Even without the CORS issues, the library does not seem to work as it should, so I'm probably looking for another option.

The intent of the library seems to be to scrape the YouTube native HTML element and read the chat messages from there, but this library seems to be deprecated and not take into consideration the YouTube cookie-consent screen.

I was thinking of mabye using Selenium and scrape the data that way, but I'm not sure if that would work. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

CORS will block any requests from your website to another website, that didn't authorize this. To solve this, write a small backend server, that uses `youtube-chat` to fetch your comments and relays it to your frontend. That way, you bypass CORS.

Comment: That could work, however I'm building a very simple app, and do not really have a need for a backend server. Also the library seems to be outdated, and I couldn't get it to work even without the CORS issues. It should also be possible to proxy the requests.